# Abrir uma janela no mouse quando clicado

Tags: python, mouse, pysimplegui

olá, eu possuo uma janela de menu feita em pysimplegui que aparece ao clicar em X lugar no meu programa.

```
def menu_window():
menu_opcoes = [
    [sg.Column([
    [sg.Button("MUDAR VALOR SELECIONADO\t",expand_x=True,enable_events=True,key="preco_item",border_width=3)],
    [sg.Button("APLICAR PERCENTUAL EM TODOS ",expand_x=True,enable_events=True,key="percentual_geral",border_width=3)],
    ])]
```

como faço para ele abrir junto ao mouse?

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi importando o pyautogui

```
    from pyautogui import position as mouse_pos


sg.window('foo', menu, margins=(0,0), 
resizable=True,location=mouse_pos()).finalize()
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).